# Do I have to adjust the general formula for an arithmetic series here?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I often find the wording of problems related to sequences and series (and financial maths by extension) confusing.

Take this problem from a textbook.

To celebrate the birth of his niece, an uncle offers to open a savings account with a deposit of €50. He also offers to every year add €10 more than he did the previous year until his niece is 21 years of age.

(i) Find an expression for $S_n$, the sum of money on deposit after n years.

(ii) Find $S_{21}$, the total saved after 21 years.

End

The first term $T_1=a=50$ and the common difference $T_{n+1}-T_n=d=10$.

The general formula for the sum of an arthmetic series is $S_n=\frac{n}{2}[2a+(n-1)d]$.

After subbing in a and d, my textbook gives the answer to (i) as $5n^2+45$ and (ii) as €3150.

Now my issue is that this formula is derived from n=1 for the first term. But in this problem, after 1 year n =2 (n=y+1).

When I sub y+1 for n I get (i) the formula $S_y=5y^2+55y+50$ and the result (ii) $S_{21}=€3410$.

Am I interpretting the problem correctly based on the wording? I find this is a common confusion especially when dealing with years as n.

Just to check, after 1 year (n=2,y=1) the account clearly has 50+60=110. My formula gives this value which gives me confidence that I am correct.

What do others think?

Comment: You did not consider, that at birth she is 0 years old not 1. so you have to start with n=0 not one.  Also It is not clear if she gets +50+20*10 on her 21. birthday.

Comment: @trula That's exactly what I "did" consider :) . My whole argument is that the textbook did not consider that. What are your answers to the problem ?

Comment: I agree with your formula and your result. The formula of the textbook is not right, no matter how someone interpret it.

Comment: @Kantura Your $€3410 = 50+60+70+\cdots +250+260$ ($22$ terms) while the book's $€3150 = 50+60+70+\cdots +250$ ($21$ terms).